# UITextField, is it possible to get the text to wrap around to another line below the first line?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've a UITextView, its quiet big, I sized it so it could fit 4 lines of text, so if the user wants to write a long note it can be read while its being written.

The problem is that text stays on the top line and it scrolls horizontally rather than wrapping around and dropping down to a line below it. Like you see when you write a text message on your phone.

Is there anything that can be done to get a UITextField to act like this? Or am I required to use an editable UITextView instead?

Looking at the docs it would seem UITextView cant provide the functionality I need.

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI,

I do'nt think , It could be possible by using `UITextField` (support single line),You will have to use the `UITextView` (for multiline text) .

See the below tutorial , It grow at runtime while the user type the text using keyboard and can expend till certain line ...

http://www.hanspinckaers.com/multi-line-uitextview-similar-to-sms

Answer (score 0):

If it is an IBOutlet than you can just enable vertical scroll and remove horizontal scroll from scrollers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No I'm not using xib for this so no IBOutlets. But if its true that this is available for UITextFields then i must be able to set it from within the code? Any idea what the accessor for this might be? I checked UITextView.window. but theres nothing in there. Anybody got an idea?